# Can I claim my girlfriend as a dependent?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

Can you claim your girlfriend as a dependent in the USA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Maybe

According to nolo.com, you can claim your partner as a dependent [if you meet five qualifications](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/claiming-unmarried-partner-dependent-tax-29735.html).

- Support: You must provide at least 50% of the support for the dependent partner.
- Residency: They must be a U.S. citizen or resident alien.
- Income: Their taxable income must be below $3900 (in 2013, up to $3950 in '14) --it's equal to the exemption amount--and you'll have to see whether the disability payments are taxable.
- Relationship: You can only claim them as a dependent if "the relationship does not violate local law". Nolo.com notes that such laws have been struck down recently where they've been challenged, so this soon may be no longer relevant.
- Marriage status: You can't claim a spouse as a legal dependent.

Comment: @jonsca - Odd time right now, working on 2013 returns, but we are in 2014, so what's "this year"? I edited for clarity sake. (You answered correctly for OP doing his '13 return of course)

Comment: @Joe Thanks for clarifying it, I'll resolve the ambiguity next time!

Comment: "They must be a U.S. citizen or legal resident alien." Nope. They need to be a resident alien for tax purposes. Illegal immigrants are all resident aliens.